# Are set-theoretically defined functions and category-theoretic morphisms equivalent notions?

Tags: functions, category-theory, set-theory, morphism

What is the relationship, if any, between set-theoretically defined functions and morphisms (or the arrow thingies) from category theory?

Comment: There's the notion of a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) which directly connects morphisms and functions, but not all categories are concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one (and to many, that's the point of "category").  The one arguable link is that the definition of a category **requires** set-theoretic functions in order to define composition, usually as a map
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \times \mathrm{Hom}(B,C) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,C).
$$

Comment: I thought maps are taken to be primitive when defining categories?

Comment: They are, but hom-sets are sets.  Composition of morphisms is then an old-fashioned function between (hom)sets as formulated above.

Comment: There are [approaches to axiomatizing categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC) that could avoid this, though no one really uses them. If we take "set-theoretic" more precisely than you perhaps intend, then we can certainly formulate categories in different foundations such as type theory. (There's also enriched categories where we've definitely inadvertently directly axiomatized specific instances.)

Comment: Isn't function an instance of morphism in category **Set**? Why can't we just state as an axiom that: $\forall f: A \rightarrow B, g: B \rightarrow C$, $\exists  h: A \rightarrow C$?

Comment: You just stated a proposed axiom that says for every $f$ and $g$ there is an $h$ (with some property, like $h= g \circ f$ and such that all associativities and blah blah blah hold) which is **exactly** the prescription of a function (for every given thing I get another output thing).  No matter how you say this, you are using functions, either implicitly or explicitly.